# exact query search in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have this query that returns if the word "mumbai" appear anywhere in the title.

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "title": "mumbai"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So the result contains...

```
mumbai
mumbai ports
financial capital mumbai
```

I need to return only "mumbai" term and not the other documents where mumbai word is associated with other phrases. Only the first result is correct. How do I discard other results?

---

update

This query is working as expected and it lists the sort value 58 (random value) if the match is exact.

```
curl -XPOST "localhost:9200/enwiki_content/page/_search?pretty" -d'
{ 
    "fields": "title",
    "query": {
        "match": {"title": "Mumbai"}
    },
    "sort": {
    "_script": {
        "script":  "_source.title == \"Mumbai\" ? \"58\": \"78\";",
        "type": "string" 

}
}
}'
```

I need to return the title where match is exact Mumbai (and hence the sort value 58). How do I filter or add the script to "fields" parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get mumbai to match with doc which contains only mumbai and nothing else, you'll have to store a token count field for the field you are searching on.
This token count field will contain the number of tokens the field contains. Using this field, you can match mumbai on your title field, and match token_count field with the number of tokens in mumbai (which is one). 
Note that token_count field in other documents will more than 1.

For reference:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/token-count.html

Note: If you are using stopwords, then you need to know about the other caveats related to token count. You can find the information in the above link.

Answer (score 1):

Try the `term` query. It will do exact match search

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "term": {
                        "title": "mumbai"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Term query will not match Mumbai and mumbai, it will be counted as different words

**Second Option:**
If you can change the mapping then you can set the `title` field as `not_analyzed`

**Third Option**

`match` query with analyzer option

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "title": {
        "query": "mumbai",
        "analyzer": "keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Note that shantanuo already has a term query and is asking for a different solution. So only your second option would be a viable option here.

Comment: Shantanuo is using filtered query which applies filter on result of match_all query in above case. Also filtered query is deprecated in 2.0-beta https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-filtered-query.html

Comment: That makes no difference, match_all is a pass-through for all documents. It would be the same if it wasn't there. What I'm saying is that your query and his are equivalent. `filtered` may be deprecated in ES 2.0, but 1) that still works and 2) we don't know whether he uses 2.0 or not. That's not the issue at hand in my opinion. I would expand on your second option instead, it's more likely what he is after.

Comment: None of these options work and I still get all 3 documents. I can not change mapping (may be because I do not know how). But is this difficult with a query?